# Symfony2 bundle configuration issue

Tags: php, symfony, configuration

I am trying to expose a custom configuration defined for my bundle which is called DecisionBundle.

I have a Decision\DecisionBundle\Resources\config\custom.yaml that looks like this:

```
decision:
    testValue: 11
    anotherTest: 12
```

I also have an Extension that looks like this:

```
namespace Decision\DecisionBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

class DecisionExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
        $loader->load('custom.yml');
    }
}
```

The file custom.yml seems to be loaded ok. Next comes the configuration interface

```
namespace Decision\DecisionBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('decision');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->scalarNode('testValue')->defaultValue('0')->end()
                ->scalarNode('anotherTest')->defaultValue('0')->end()
            ->end();

        // Here you should define the parameters that are allowed to
        // configure your bundle. See the documentation linked above for
        // more information on that topic.

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

However, this results in the following:

```
InvalidArgumentException: There is no extension able to load the configuration for "decision" (in *****\src\Decision\DecisionBundle\DependencyInjection/../Resources/config\custom.yml). Looked for namespace "decision", found none
```

Can somebody point me as to what I am doing wrong? Do I need to manually register the Extension somehow? However, the Extension seems taken into account as it looks loaded from the debug info. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are setting parameters in your `custom.yml` file in the same way that you would set them in the `app/config/config.yml' file.

```
decision:
    testValue: 11
    anotherTest: 12
```

When you are loading a file through the configuration file then your service files (`services.yml` & `custom.yml` in your case) should have either `services` or `parameters` as the headers. To use your parameters in the `custom.yml` file you should lay it out like..

```
parameters:
    decision.testValue: 11
    decision.anotherTest: 12
```

Also, if you are putting the parameters in the `app/config/config.yml` file, you need to set them to actual parameters in your `DecisionExtension`. To do this you would need to get the data from your `Configuration` file and set them in the container like..

```
$configuration = new Configuration();
$config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

$loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new 
                                  FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
$loader->load('services.yml');
$loader->load('custom.yml');

$container->setParameter('decision.testValue', $config['testValue']);
$container->setParameter('decision.anotherTest', $config['anotherTest']);
```

This, however, will overwrite the parameters set in your `custom.yml` and also negate any reason for it being there.